# How to open Experience Editor with Preview mode in a new tab?

Tags: experience-editor

The requirement is to open Experience Editor in the Preview mode in a new tab.

Comment: Do you mean you need "preview" mode to open in a new browser tab when you click "Preview" button in Content Editor like EE does open in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use sc_mode=preview URL parameter:

- [www.mysite.com?sc_mode=preview](http://www.mysite.com?sc_mode=preview)
- [www.mysite.com?my_firstparam=1&sc_mode=preview](http://www.mysite.com?my_firstparam=1&sc_mode=preview)

If you need to open a link in the tab then you need to use target="_blank":

```
<a href="www.mysite.com?sc_mode=preview" target="_blank">my site in preview mode</a>
```

Or you can use Sitecore options if you're using link fields or RTE fields.